# Making strings by pointers

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I have learned that a pointer points to a memory address so i can use it to alter the value set at that address. So like this:

```
int *pPointer = &iTuna;
```

`pPointer` here has the memory address of `iTuna`. So we can use `pPointer` to alter the value at `iTuna`. If I print `pPointer` the memory address gets printed and if I print `*pPointer` then the value at `iTuna` gets printed

Now see this program

```
    char* pStr= "Hello !";
cout<< pStr << endl;
cout<< *pStr << endl;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

There are a lot of stuff I don't understand here:

1. In "Hello !" Each letter is stored separately, and a pointer holds one memory address. So how does `pStr` point to all the letters.
2. Also When I print out `pStr` it prints *Hello !*, not a memory address.
3. And when I print out `*pStr` it prints out *H* only not all what `pStr` is pointing too.

I really can't understand and these are my concerns. I hope someone can explain to me how this works ad help me understand

Comment: Please get rid of the [system("pause")](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html).

Comment: I don't quite like that article, because a beginner (the most likely audience) will find himself very confused if cin.get() or getchar() won't pause after an input operation.

Comment: `char* pStr= "Hello !";` is deprecated, use `char const*`.

Comment: @Cubic, Yeah, you have to work around it by using either one or two of them, or you can rely on the non-guaranteed behaviour of `cin.sync` before calling `cin.get`. Or you can just use it like a normal console application instead of trying to make it a standalone app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. `"Hello !"` is an **array** of type `char const[8]` and value `{ 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', '!', 0 }`. `pStr` is a pointer to its first element; its last element has the value `0`.
2. There is an overload in the iostreams library for a `char const *` argument, which treats the ar­gu­ment as a pointer to the first element of an array and prints every element until it encounters a zero. ("Null-ter­mi­nat­ed string" in colloquial parlance.)
3. Dereferencing the pointer to the first element of an array gives you the first element of the array, i.e. `'H'`. This identical to `pStr[0]`.

Comment: Great answer. One thing, What do you mean there is an overload in the iostreams library for a char2 argument

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil: There's simply an definition of an overload `namespace std { ostream & operator<<(ostream & o, char const * s); }` which is implemented as something like `for ( ; *s; ++s) { o << *s} return o;`. When you say `std::cout << pStr;`, that overload is invoked, i.e. the actual call is `operator<<(std::cout, pStr)`.

Comment: `char const`, ***`char const`***!

Comment: @Xeo: Naturally. What did *I* say?

Comment: You missed the string literal type.

Comment: @Xeo: Oh, of course -- I was somehow imagining we'd be initializing an array somewhere and taking a pointer to that... but of course the type of the literal *is* const, and the OP's code is just wrong(ish).

Comment: your comment made no sense to me to me since im not that advanced in C++ yet. Can you please explain in simpler words. And also please tell me the definition of overload

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil: The following are legal: 1) `char const * s = "Hello";` 2) `char arr[] = "Hello", * s = arr;` The former makes `s` a pointer to some anonymous, read-only storage; the latter creates a local array and makes `s` a pointer to *that*. What you wrote is neither of those.

Answer (score 2):

1-) Since `pStr` points to a `char`, it actually points to the beginning of an array of a [`null terminated string`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string)

2-) `cout` is overloaded with a `char *` argument. It will print out ever character in the string until it reaches the `null character`

3-) You are dereferencing the pointer to the first element of the character array.

Answer (score 1):

> 1-) In "Hello !" Each letter is stored seperatly, and a pointer holds
>   one memory adress. So how does pStr point to all the letters.

The letters are stored in that order in each memory cell with an extra final cell 
holding 0 to mark the end.

> 2-)Also When i print out pStr it prints Hello ! not a memory adress.

The `cout <<` understands that you are pointing at a string and so prints the string.

> 3-)And when i print out *pStr it prints out H only not all what pStr
>   is pointng too.

The `*` means you are askign for the value at that address.  `cout <<`  knows that the address holds a char and so prints the char.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of pointers is correct in all respects.

Your problem is that the << operator has been overridden for various datatypes on a stream. So the standard library writers have MADE the operator << do something specific on any variable of the type char * (in this case the something specific means output the characters at that address until you get to the end of string marker) as opposed to what you expect it to do (print an address in decimal or hex)

Similarly the << operator has been overridden for char to just output a single character, if you think about it for a bit you will realise that *pStr is a dereferenced pointer to a character - that is it is a char - thus it just prints a single char.

Comment: What does "overridden" means?

Comment: in c++it is possible to overload operator (like + or >>) for specific types: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Operators_and_operator_overloading

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to understand concept of strings as well. In C and C++, string is a few characters (char's) located one after another in a memory, basically, 'H','e','l','l','o','\0'. Your pointer holds memory address of the first symbol, and your C++ library knows that a string is everything starting this address and ending with '\0'.
2. When you pass char* to cout, it knows you output a string, and prints it as a string.
3. Construction *pStr means "give me whatever is located at address stored in pStr". That would be char - a single character - 'H', which is then passed to cout, and you get only one character printed.

Answer (score 1):

1. A pointer, `*pStr` points to a specific memory address, but that memory address can be used not only as a single element, i.e. a `char`, but also as the beginning of an *array* of such elements, or a block of memory.
2. `char` arrays are a special type of array in C in that some operations handle them in a specific way: as a *string*. Hence, `printf("%s", ...` and `cout` know that when given a `char *` they should look for a string, and print all the characters until the terminating `null` character. Furthermore, C provides a *string library* with functions designed to manipulate such `char *` as strings.
3. This behavior is just as you'd expect from your own analysis: de-referencing `pStr` simply gives you the value at the memory address, in this case the first element of an array of `chars` in memory.

Answer (score 0):

1. A pointer to an array (a C style string is an array of char) is just a pointer to the first element of the array.
2. The << operator is overloaded for the type char* to treat it as a C-style string, so when you pass it a char* it starts at the pointer you give it and keeps adding 1 to it to find the next character until it finds the null character which signals the end of the string.
3. When you dereference the pointer you the type you get is char because the pointer only actually points to the first item in the array. The overload of << for char doesn't treat it as a string, just as a single character.

Using strings like this is C-style code. When using C++ you should instead use std::string. It is much easier to use.