# Why doesn't a character array return a memory address when called directly?

Tags: c++

I understand from [here](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch2x.htm) that the name of an array is the address of the first element in the array, so this makes sense to me:

```
int nbrs[] = {1,2};
cout << nbrs << endl;   // Outputs: 0x28ac60
```

However, why is the entire C-string returned here and not the address of `ltrs`?

```
char ltrs[] = "foo";
cout << ltrs << endl;   // Outputs: foo
```

Comment: Because it's been overloaded to print the string for convenience.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: Making strings by pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798233/c-making-strings-by-pointers)

Comment: A name of an array is _not_ the address of the first item.  They're very different.  However, an array will _sometimes_ pretend to be a pointer to the first item.

Comment: Also the entire C-string is being displayed, not "returned"

Comment: You're writing C++ rather than C. I would recommend you find a good C++ tutorial instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because iostreams have an overload for `char *` that prints out what the pointer refers to, up to the first byte that contains a `\0`.

If you want to print out the address, cast to `void *` first.

Answer (score 4):

`cout` has `operator<<()` overloaded for char* arrays so that it outputs every element of the array until it reaches a null character rather than outputting the address of the pointer

Answer (score 2):

`cout`, and generally, C++ streams, can handle C strings in a special way. `cout` operators `<<`, `>>` are overloaded to handle a number of different things, and this is one of them.